# WorkflowInstance aborts when persisting

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have got workflow instances running in a `WorkflowServiceHost`. The workflow is built as a state machine. I'm using the out of the box `SqlWorkflowPersistenceService`, configured with `UnloadOnIdle = true` and a instance lock time of 5 minutes (tried different values here).

These workflow instances are long running, when they wait to receive a message many hours or days can possibly elapse.

I now have got the problem that if a workflow instance is waiting for a message, this message must arrive within the lock time (a date in the InstanceState table), or **after receiving the message the instance aborts as soon as the next persistence point is hit**.

I always thought the lock time must be equal or longer than the max. duration between persistence points. It appears as when a message is received by the workflow instance, the lock time doesn't get updated in the InstanceState table.

Any ideas what could be done?